# ListBlobs not visible in list of functions in microsoft.azurestorage

Tags: c#, azure, blobs

I work on an aspnetcore 2.0 project.

I want to use Blob AzureStorage, and I need to list the files in a container.

I added the nuget WindowsAzure.Storage 8.4.

using this line of code:

```
    var results = container.ListBlobs();
```

I see an error saying CloudBlobContainer does not contain a definition for ListBlobs.

Anyone got this error before?

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [`Github issue`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/367), sync methods are not implemented in .Net Core/.Net Standard version of the library. From this issue:

> Thanks for bringing this up. You are right. Our NetCore/Netstandard
>   support does not yet include Sync implementation of the APIs. Please
>   note that this change is on our Roadmap as one of the parity items for
>   the transition to .NetCore and we will update with more specific
>   timelines as soon as it is available.

Even though the issue is 1st reported for Storage Client Library version 7.2.1, but looking at the [`Roadmap`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/338), this issue is still open.

You may want to ask this question on [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/367) to check the status of this particular issue.